# Refresh all data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have seen quite a few threads on refreshing a JTable using:

```
String[] columnNames = {"column1","column2,......,"columnN"};
String[][] tableData = new String[1][columnNames.length];
JTable table = new JTable(tableData,columnNames);

JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
contentPane.add(scrollpane);
```

... make a change to the data stored in `tableData` then call...

```
AbstractTableModel model = (AbstractTableModel) table.getModel();
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

But this doesn't seem to change anything for me. I need to initially show display a blank table with one row and then update it when the user loads a data file however the code below doesn't seem to work for me. I assume its because im redefining `tableData` but this has to be done as i do not know how many rows of data are to be displayed until the user loads a file. How can I update the table?

---

**Edit:**
To make it clearer the code i am running is:

```
//Initialize Table With 1 Blank Row
String[] columnNames = {"column1","column2,......,"columnN"};
String[][] tableData = new String[1][columnNames.length];
JTable table = new JTable(tableData,columnNames);

JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
contentPane.add(scrollpane);

//When the file is loaded resize tableData so it can fit all the file data
tableData = new String[length of data file][columnNames.length];

//Update some of the tableData points
tableData[0][0]="data 1";
tableData[1][0]="data 2";
tableData[0][1]="data 3";
tableData[1][1]="data 4";
....etc

//Tell the JTable to update
AbstractTableModel model = (AbstractTableModel) table.getModel();
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: Post the code where you update the table model.

Comment: @Makky Ive posted the code where i update tableData. I then call model.fireTableDataChanged() but nothing changes.

Comment: You should never invoke a fireXXX method directly. That is the responsibility of the TableModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is when you create JTable you're not assigning any model to it.

See below example :

**Its too much in here ,but you'll get the idea.**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TestGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestGUI window = new TestGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(60, 81, 311, 96);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        String[] columnNames = { "column1", "column2", "columnN" };
        String[][] tableData = new String[1][columnNames.length];
        table = new JTable(tableData, columnNames);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(2, columnNames.length);
        model.addRow(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });
        table.setModel(model);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("update");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                model.addRow(new String[] { "A", "B", "D" });

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(49, 199, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can completely overwrite the old tableModel? say if i loaded one file then loaded another with completely different data i would need to resize and reset the table completely. It seems inefficient to remove each row individually and then add a new one.

Comment: Create a new TableModel with your data then use the `table.setModel(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your example will never working because the `DefaultTableModel` (which is used here by default) will copy all your array data into internal vector-object. So your changes in original array will never be propagated to the internal structure of `DefaultTableModel`.

Use `DefaultTableModel` directly to avoid your problem.